# Can't walk dependency graph: Cannot find module '../../support/pageObjects/TeamPage

Tags: bdd, cypress

It is the first time I am running a specific BDD cypress test and I got the following

```
Error: Can't walk dependency graph: Cannot find module '../../support/pageObjects/TeamPage' from 'D:\Repos\vjtrck\cypress\integration\features\Team\team.spec.js'
    required by D:\Repos\vjtrck\cypress\integration\features\Team\team.spec.js
    at D:\Repos\vjtrck\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:167:35
    at load (D:\Repos\vjtrck\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:186:43)
    at onex (D:\Repos\vjtrck\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:211:17)
    at D:\Repos\vjtrck\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:24:69
    at callback (C:\Users\ingridd\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\9.7.0\Cypress\resources\app\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:299:20)
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21)
```

I have all set: feature file, spec.file and Page Object. The names are correct and they are on the correct paths.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue, you can try the following steps:

1 Verify the file path: Double-check that the file path `'../../support/pageObjects/TeamPage'` is correct and matches the actual location of the TeamPage module. Ensure that the file extension is also correct (e.g., .js).

2 Check the file name: Make sure that the file name matches the module name exactly, including any capitalization or letter case. Ensure that there are no spelling errors or typos in the file name.

3 Validate the file import statement: In your test file (`team.spec.js`), verify that the import statement for the TeamPage module is correctly referencing the file path and file name. The import statement should match the file path and module name exactly.

For example:

```
import TeamPage from '../../support/pageObjects/TeamPage';
```

4 Confirm the file location: Ensure that the TeamPage module is located in the correct directory (`'../../support/pageObjects/'`) relative to the test file (`team.spec.js`). Check if the file is present in that directory and that it has the correct file extension (`.js`).

5 Clear Cypress cache: If the above steps do not resolve the issue, you can try clearing the Cypress cache. Run the following command in your project directory:

```
npx cypress cache clear
```

This command clears the Cypress cache, which can sometimes resolve issues related to module dependencies.

After performing these steps, try running your BDD Cypress test again and see if the error persists. If the issue still persists, please provide more details about your project structure, the specific file paths, and the import statements. This will help in further troubleshooting.